# Combining a single custom exception with an enum to easily create several sub-exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception, c#-5.0

I think I am need of writing one or more custom exceptions in C# 5.0. I am probably not, but it seems that the .NET provided exceptions belong to a too-systemic and too-generic domain of exceptions - very much specific to situation of "having a running program on the CLR supporting file I/O". This IS exactly what I have, at least, of course. Still, when trying to develop an application in C# or any other OO-language, a subset (or all) of the new types that you create, should in most circumstances originate from an ontology of concepts, which is nowhere close to such a systemic domain as the CLR or the .NET Framework. That's how I see the "authoring" part of OO development - but that's an entire different question really.

So, on the "problem" of creating custom exceptions, I wanted to hear if the following solution have any drawbacks.

Let's say I create this enum and custom exception:

```
public enum MyCustomExceptionKind
{
    MyCustomInitializationException,
    MyCustomStartException,
    MyCustomStopException,
    MyCustomFatalException
}

public class MyCustomException: Exception
{
    private MyCustomExceptionKind? m_exceptionKind = null;

    public MyCustomExceptionKind ExceptionKind
    {
        // return the value of the nullable type:
        get { return m_exceptionKind.Value; }
    }

    // let's support only the most-exclicit instance constructor for now:
    public EmployeeListNotFoundException(
        MyCustomExceptionKind myCustomExceptionkind,
        string message,
        Exception inner): base(message, inner)
    {
        m_exceptionKind = myCustomExceptionkind;
    }
}
```

The idea here, is the use of a built-in enumeration type. Instead of creating many new exception, I have chosen to use an enum for encoding the sub-type on an exception. Note that I also take use of a nullable enum-type by using the question-mark.

Handling such an exception would then behave something like this:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public void StartUniverse(int num)
    {
        if (num != 42)
        {
            throw new MyCustomException(
                MyCustomExceptionKind.AttemptToStart,
                "It was not possible start the damn thing ...",
                null);
        }
    }

    public bool TryStart(int num)
    {
        tryOK = true;
        try
        {
            StartUniverse(num);
        }
        catch (MyCustomException ex)
        {
            // set the overall state-bool to false:
            tryOK = false;

            // use a switch case for handling sub-types of this exception:
            switch (MyCustomException.ExceptionKind)
            {
                    case MyCustomExceptionKind.MyCustomStartException:
                    Trace.TraceError("oh dear - could not start");
                    break;
            }
        }
        return tryOK;
    }

    static public Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myObj = new SomeType();
        myObj.TryStart(199); // <-- 199 != 42
    }
}
```

Anything to be aware of in such an implementation? Pros and cons? From where I stand, I see only good things. That's usually an illusion though.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to perform different actions based on the exception kind? In fact, do you really need to perform different actions when your custom exception is thrown versus any other exception?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I would probably not use more than one case in the switch at any exception-handler. The idea was, that I could apply the same single exception-class for different exception handlers in methods in another class. So I would not have to create a new type for any special sub-exception in that other class. And yes, there could be special sub-exceptions taking place. Mostly based on faulty object state than wrong user input.

Comment: But do you need to behave differently based on faulty object states? Why not have a single "FaultyObjectStateException"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approch is okay, as long as all ExceptionKinds are on the same level: all exception can be handled on the same layer and will result in the same handling (like showing a message box or stopping a task).
But for instance, when `MyCustomFatalException` should result in a program termination, then your approach is not the best, cause you would need to catch it twice

```
void DoStuff()
{
    try
    {
       ...
    }
    catch(MyCustomException inner)
    {
       if (inner.ExceptionKind == MyCustomExceptionKind.MyCustomFatalException)
          throw;

       // handle inner, show message box
    }
}

void DoStuffTwice()
{
   DoStuff();
   DoStuff();
}    


void Main()
{
   try
   {
       DoStuffTwice();
   }
   catch(MyCustomException inner)
   {
       if (inner.ExceptionKind == MyCustomExceptionKind.MyCustomFatalException)
          return;

       // now what??
   }
}
```

this does not look like a big deal, but on heavy load that may introduce a problem, because catching exceptions costs time, and catching an exception without the need of handling it, and just of the purpose of rethrowing it, can slow down your application.

BTW: I don't understand why you choose to make the `ExceptionKind`property return nullable value, since it can never be null.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct about the use of Nullable<> - I guess I do not really need that. Although the property does not return the nullable type, but value only. I guess I like to be able to initialize an enum type to something else than one of the values (non-initialized it still defaults to the first value). Therefore null became my choice. But that's not necessary here, true.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that writing several different exception classes is effort you pay **once**; handling the different exception scenarios may come up many times.  So try to focus on making this easier for the client that's going to handle these exceptions.

Compare the boilerplate of catching the general exception, peeking inside to check if it's actually relevant, and rethrowing otherwise, versus just catching a specialized exception type that you know you care about.  The facilities to catch specific exception types and to derive new exception types work together to make it easier to just use specialized exception types than to use general exception types otherwise marked with special values.  Don't work against the grain of the language.

If you anticipate your client wanting to catch all of your custom exceptions at the same site, you can make your custom exceptions inherit from a common MyCustomException class.  This is essentially a superset of your enum solution; if someone catches the general MyCustomException class and then for whatever reason needs to know the specific type, they can just say (ex is MyCustomInitializationException).  But you've still given your users the option to catch MyCustomInitializationException in the first place if that's what they care about.

Comment: Yea okay - good point. I've found myself sometimes not carrying about the specific exception type. I sometimes just catch Exception() and convert the event of some code failing, into a bool (the tryX()/X() pattern). This is mostly with some System.IO methods that seem to be able to throw a "large" number of exceptions that I simply do not know how to deal with - other than possibly log their  occurrence to a TraceListener and then reducing the whole thing to a state of utter failure.

Comment: Edited to address the desire to catch all of the custom exception types.

Answer (score 0):

If the exceptions are really the same thing with a different code (Like HttpStatus), then it makes sense.  Otherwise I would create different Exception classes.